# postfix how to allow domain but block subdomains

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix mail gateway that passes mail to and from a domain.  I want it to reject mail to or from subdomains of that domain.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple fix that seems to work OK.

There is a postfix command postconf.

postconf -d :shows all the default values of settings.

postconf -n :shows all the settings in main.cf

There is a setting which is not referenced in my main.cf which shows this as it's default:

```
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,
  permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
```

According to postfix access

```
man 5 access
```

or http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html

removing the value smtpd_access_maps from this setting turns off subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Put this is /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Put this in /etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
/^To:\ .*@.*\.yourdomain\.tld/    DISCARD NO SUBDOMAINS
```

Run these commands:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
systemctl restart postfix
```